# BeforeNavigate2 event does not work on 32-bit Windows 7 Internet Explorer 11

Tags: c#, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, bho, beforenavigate2

I have implemented a BHO in C#, which uses the BeforeNavigate2 event. It is working in Internet Explorer 11 on a 64-bit Windows 7 system.

On a 32-bit Windows 7 system the BeforeNavigate2 event is not triggered. But the SetSite method is called.

Why is the BeforeNavigate2 event not triggered on 32-bit?
What is the exact difference between 32-bit and 64-bit Internet Explorer 11, that could cause this behaviour?